# regex how to remove the emotion characters

Tags: regex

This is my string and I want to remove all the emotions string/characters from here, searching for a while but getting not luck, I am not good at regex at all.

I have tried :   ((>|<|q)?[=:8;]{1}(')?(-)?[><)(/cdopsx:^*]) but only managed to remove few

emotion character: :), :(, :D ,(cool) , :o , :* ,:P , :$ , :^) ,, |-), |-( , (inlove) 
        ]:)(yn)  (yawn)
        (puke)  (doh ) 
        (angry) (wasntme) (party)
        (worry) (mm) (nerd) :x (wave)
        (facepalm) (devi l) (angel)
        (envy) (wait) (hug) (makeup) (chuckle) (clap)

```
:) how :( fgdfg :D ghjgh
    (cool) dfgdf :o dfd :* dsfdf
    :P dsf :$ dfv :^) dfgd g |-)
    dfg |-( dfgd g (inlove) dfd
    ]:) d f s (yn) dsf (yawn) fg
    (puke) fggf (doh ) fgg
    (angry) (wasntme) (party)
    (worry) (mm) (nerd) :x (wave)
    (facepalm) (devi l) (angel)
    (envy) (wait) (hug) (makeup) (chuckle) (clap)
```

http://rubular.com/r/PGgnlYRrhQ[1](http://rubular.com/r/PGgnlYRrhQ)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please specify which of the characters you consider “emotion characters”.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think regex is the way to go here.  You probably should just do a string.split on spaces and a dictionary or list of "emotion characters".  Then you go through each word and remove the bad ones.  Then you put the string back together again.  Or you use a whole bunch or regex replaces with \b for start of word boundary and do a replace for each individual term.